# modifying the PS file to thick the line

Tags: postscript

I have a .ps file and I want to increase the line widths of the main axis (major and minor ticks). Which property in the ps file is the right one to change.

The ps file is available [here](http://pastebin.com/w3w3sefk) and you can see the output file below.

[image]

**UPDATE**

**UPDATE**

According to the [BlueBook](http://pastebin.com/w3w3sefk) (pages 21 and 25) and the [GreenBook](http://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/GREENBK.PDF) (page 41), the setlinewidth syntax is something like

```
4 setlinewidth
```

However, in my file, the setlinewidth is called like this

```
/sw /setlinewidth load def
```

It seems that this is a different syntax! I also wrote something like a piece of code to pop a value (3) and set it to linewidth (at least I think)

```
{ dup 0 eq
  { pop 3
  } if
  setlinewidth
} bind def
/sw /setlinewidth load def
```

But it incorrect.

I appreciate if someone help me how to change the linewidth because I am not really going to write a printer driver....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add a few supplementary words to accompany Ken's answer, which is IMO the correct view. The basics of the language can be gleaned by checking the [Postscript tag-info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postscript/info). Read the first half of the blue book (it's very short and gets you up to speed with the stacks and operators and syntax and everything). Then you should read the green book for background on why the program is structured as it is with a prolog that defines lots of short names, and a script that looks more like pure data.

If you do that, then you will find that Ken really has given you the answer of how to do it by modifying the postscript. But it is also very true that a "better" way is almost always to re-generate the postscript by modifying the actual source material (whatever that may be, it probably has something closer to a "property" for that element).

---

*Edit: after question update.*

As Ken said, you don't actually need to mess with the line

```
/sw /setlinewidth load def
```

This isn't calling `setlinewidth`, but defining `sw` as a shortcut for the longer name.

So, for each section there are 2 things you need to do:

1. change the linewidth at the start
2. change it back at the end

To change the width relative to its current value, you can use `currentlinewidth` and do a little math.

```
currentlinewidth 2 mul setlinewidth
```

To change it back, you can do the inverse operation, or bracket the whole thing with an extra `gsave` ... `grestore` pair, or save the original width in a definition and use the definition to reset it.

You can use either the long operator names like `gsave` or the shortcuts defined in the program, like `gs`.

Comment: Does it matter where to put `currentlinewidth 2 mul setlinewidth`?

Comment: As you said, the sw is an abbreviation. So I searched for sw and saw many "0 sw". I think that means assigning 0 to the sw. So I replaced it with "1 sw" and now I see thicker lines on the axis. Many thanks...

Comment: @mahmood I see. Yes, `0 sw` can definitely cause problems like you've encountered. It sets the width to the very minimum size available on the device <-- bad news at very high resolutions. With `1 sw` or really, anything except `0`, you can scale the drawing and the widths will scale automatically. But with 0, it's impossible to *zoom*, because you can't scale it (numerically).

Comment: FWIW the same answer (don't use 0 setlinewidth) was given in reply to this question on the gs-devel mailing list. A line width of 0 is defined as a 'hairline', the narrowest line its possible to draw on the device (ie 1 pixel). Clearly this results in different output at 72 dpi and 2540 dpi. There can be good reasons for using a hairline, but its usually best avoided.

Comment: @KenS, yes that was me :) To be honest, it took time for me to understand what Perry said. Not because I am new to linux! but for the reason that I am new to postscript language and concepts.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, this isn't a sensible question. PostScript is a programming language, so asking which 'property' to change doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If you want the printed result to be different, you should go back to the original application which produced the PostScript, and modify that.

Which of the two axes do you consider to be the 'major' axis ?

This section of code:

```
gs
a 113 2 m 113 292 l ps
gr
gs
a ps
a 113 6.40922 m 107.5 6.40922 l ps
a 113 18.0718 m 102 18.0718 l ps
a 113 29.7345 m 107.5 29.7345 l 113 41.3971 m 107.5 41.3971 l 113 53.0597 m 107.5 53.0597 l 113 64.7223 m 107.5 64.7223 l 113 76.3849 m 107.5 76.3849 l 113 88.0476 m 107.5 88.0476 l 113 99.7102 m 107.5 99.7102 l 113 111.373 m 107.5 111.373 l 113 123.035 m 107.5 123.035 l 113 134.698 m 107.5 134.698 l ps
80 18.0718 m (0) s
a 113 134.698 m 102 134.698 l ps
a 113 146.361 m 107.5 146.361 l 113 158.023 m 107.5 158.023 l 113 169.686 m 107.5 169.686 l 113 181.349 m 107.5 181.349 l 113 193.011 m 107.5 193.011 l 113 204.674 m 107.5 204.674 l 113 216.336 m 107.5 216.336 l 113 227.999 m 107.5 227.999 l 113 239.662 m 107.5 239.662 l 113 251.324 m 107.5 251.324 l ps
42 123.698 m (500m) s
a 113 251.324 m 102 251.324 l ps
a 113 262.987 m 107.5 262.987 l 113 274.65 m 107.5 274.65 l 113 286.312 m 107.5 286.312 l 113 297.975 m 107.5 297.975 l 113 309.637 m 107.5 309.637 l 113 321.3 m 107.5 321.3 l 113 332.963 m 107.5 332.963 l 113 344.625 m 107.5 344.625 l 113 356.288 m 107.5 356.288 l 113 367.95 m 107.5 367.95 l ps
80 240.324 m (1) s
a 113 303.663 m 107.5 303.663 l 113 315.325 m 107.5 315.325 l 113 326.988 m 107.5 326.988 l 113 338.65 m 107.5 338.65 l 113 350.313 m 107.5 350.313 l 113 361.976 m 107.5 361.976 l 113 373.638 m 107.5 373.638 l 113 385.301 m 107.5 385.301 l 113 396.964 m 107.5 396.964 l 113 408.626 m 107.5 408.626 l ps
gr
```

draws the short axis (labelled as Voltages (lin), and this section of code:

```
gs
a 2 64 m 709 64 l ps
gr
gs
a 2 64 m 2 53 l ps
a ps
a ps
a 22.2859 64 m 22.2859 53 l ps
a 49.4608 64 m 49.4608 58.5 l 76.6357 64 m 76.6357 58.5 l 103.811 64 m 103.811 58.5 l 130.986 64 m 130.986 58.5 l 158.161 64 m 158.161 58.5 l ps
11.7859 31 m (4n) s
a 158.161 64 m 158.161 53 l ps
a 185.335 64 m 185.335 58.5 l 212.51 64 m 212.51 58.5 l 239.685 64 m 239.685 58.5 l 266.86 64 m 266.86 58.5 l 294.035 64 m 294.035 58.5 l ps
139.661 31 m (4.2n) s
a 294.035 64 m 294.035 53 l ps
a 321.21 64 m 321.21 58.5 l 348.385 64 m 348.385 58.5 l 375.56 64 m 375.56 58.5 l 402.735 64 m 402.735 58.5 l 429.91 64 m 429.91 58.5 l ps
275.535 31 m (4.4n) s
a 429.91 64 m 429.91 53 l ps
a 457.085 64 m 457.085 58.5 l 484.26 64 m 484.26 58.5 l 511.435 64 m 511.435 58.5 l 538.609 64 m 538.609 58.5 l 565.784 64 m 565.784 58.5 l ps
411.41 31 m (4.6n) s
a 565.784 64 m 565.784 53 l ps
a 592.959 64 m 592.959 58.5 l 620.134 64 m 620.134 58.5 l 647.309 64 m 647.309 58.5 l 674.484 64 m 674.484 58.5 l 701.659 64 m 701.659 58.5 l ps
547.284 31 m (4.8n) s
a 701.659 64 m 701.659 53 l ps
a 728.834 64 m 728.834 58.5 l 756.009 64 m 756.009 58.5 l 783.184 64 m 783.184 58.5 l 810.359 64 m 810.359 58.5 l 837.534 64 m 837.534 58.5 l ps
688 20 m (5n) s
a 709 64 m 709 53 l ps
a 736.175 64 m 736.175 58.5 l 763.35 64 m 763.35 58.5 l 790.525 64 m 790.525 58.5 l 817.7 64 m 817.7 58.5 l 844.875 64 m 844.875 58.5 l ps
gr
```

draws the other axis. If you alter the linewidth in those sections, then the strokes will be wider.

Comment: That is good. May I ask which parameter is the linewidth? Do you mean `53 l`?

Comment: No, line width is set by the setlinewidth operator. '53 l' means 'put the value 53 on the operand stack, then execute the named object l' (or more accurately put the value 2 on the operand stack and then put the value 53). In this case you can see in the prolog that the name /l is defined as '/lineto /load'. That is, its identical to the lineto operator. So this means, from the current point draw a line to x=2, y=53 and add that to the current path. If you want to modify PostScript programs, you really will have to get at least as basic grasp of the language.

Comment: Again thanks for the explanation. In fact, I am going to modify this chart once or all! because I see the ps file contains the data that our unfriendly application has little options for such modifications. the linewidth line is `/sw /setlinewidth load def`. I replaced "def" or "load def" with a number but seems to be incorrect.

Comment: That line defines the named object /sw as the operator 'etlinewidth', you need to provide a number. You don't need to alter that line, you need to alter the numeric value used as a parameter, so you need to change the value pushed onto the operand stack immediately before 'sw' is executed. Note that the value is interpreted in user space and so is subject to the Current Transformation Matrix.when rendering to device space. Your problem is that PostScript is a programming language, you can't randomly poke bits of a program and hope to achieve a useful result, you need to understand the program.